# Chaining network calls with Promises

Tags: ios, swift, promise

I'm using the promise library at `https://github.com/khanlou/Promise`

If I want to chain multiple network calls, how would I go about it? Each call has a different set of parameters and returns a Promise<[String:Any]>

Ideally, I would just store the results of each .then closure and simply return the next call:

```
  typealias GetPromise = Promise<[String:Any]>

  getDomains(baseDomain: credentials.baseDomain).then({ domains in
     self.domains = domains
     return self.getConfiguration(baseDomain: credentials.baseDomain, brandId: credentials.brandId)
  }).then({ configuration in
     self.configuration = configuration
     return self.getServerTime(baseDomain: credentials.baseDomain)
  }).then({ serverTime in
     self.serverTime = serverTime
     resultsBlock(Results.success)
  }).catch { (error) in
     resultsBlock(Results.error(error))
  }
```

Unfortunately that violates the non-void return value in voice function rule.

So then I tried to return the results of each call with the promise in the next as a tuple, but that caused destructuring issues:

```
  typealias GetPromise = Promise<[String:Any]>

  getDomains(baseDomain: credentials.baseDomain).then({ domains in
     return (domains, self.getConfiguration(baseDomain: credentials.baseDomain, brandId: credentials.brandId))
  }).then({ (domains, configuration) in
     return (domains, configuration, self.getServerTime(baseDomain: credentials.baseDomain))
  }).then({ (domains, configuration, serverTime) in
     resultsBlock(Results.succes)
  }).catch { (error) in
     resultsBlock(Results.error(error))
  }
```

Here are my method definitions:

```
   private func getDomains(baseDomain: String) -> GetPromise {
      return get(urlPath: discoveryPath)
   }

   private func getConfiguration(baseDomain: String, brandId: String) -> GetPromise {
      return get(urlPath: configurationPath)
   }

   private func getServerTime(baseDomain: String) -> GetPromise {
      return get(urlPath: serverTimePath)
   }

   private func get(urlPath: String) -> GetPromise {
      return GetPromise(work: { fulfill, reject in
         guard let url = URL(string: urlPath) else {
            reject(ConnectionManager.basicError)
            return
         }

         let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, _, error) in
            if let error = error {
               reject(error)
               return
            }

            if let data = data
               , let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
               , let dictValue = jsonObject as? [String:Any] {
               fulfill(dictValue)
               return
            }

            reject(ConnectionManager.basicError)
         }

         task.resume()
      })
   }
```

Any ideas? Perhaps Promises is not the way to go here and there's a way of wrapping network calls in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

From the owner of the product:

Your first bit of code works, just fine, you just need to a return type to the block. For example, configuration -> Promise<[String: Any]> in. This is because blocks longer than one line don't have their types inferred in Swift.

If all the requests are completely independent, you can use Promises.zip.

```
Promises.zip(
    getDomains(baseDomain: credentials.baseDomain),
    self.getConfiguration(baseDomain: credentials.baseDomain, brandId: credentials.brandId),
    self.getServerTime(baseDomain: credentials.baseDomain)
).then({ (domains, configuration, time) in
   // save all data
```

Hope that helps.